# Unable to resolve module react-native-fbads could not be found within the project or in these directories

Tags: react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk, react-native-fbads

Unable to resolve module react-native-fbads from D:\BetaApps\DemoApp\allFiles\Screens\HomeScreen.js: react-native-fbads could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules
Getting this error again and again i have already insalled fbsdk next  in my application

I have installed fbsdk next in my react native app after that i have installed the react native fbads and it always gives this type of error Unable to resolve module react-native-fbads from D:\BetaApps\DemoApp\allFiles\Screens\HomeScreen.js: react-native-fbads could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.